# Android notification reloads everything

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am learning Android's notification system, but I have a problem. I am using this code for issue a notification:

```
private void notBuild() {
  int mId=1;
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.twitter)
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setNumber(15);

  // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  resultIntent.putExtra("sss","tolgay007");

  // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
  // started Activity.
  // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
  // your application to the Home screen.
  TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

  // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
  stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

  // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
  stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
  PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
  mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
  mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

}
```

If I issue a notification and then if I press the home button (I mean pausing app) when I return the app(resuming app) main activity is reloading and all variables is returning null. But If I not issue a notification, there is a no problem. I don't want to reload everything if I issue a notification.
How can I do this ?

Ps:I want to run main activity from notification but I don't want to reload just resume it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```